# SQL Server - Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I'm needing some help. I have two columns, Place and Name, I want a count of Name for each place. Currently the data would look like:

```
Place | Name
100     OK
100     NEW
100     BAD  
200     BAD
200     BAD
300     OK
400     OK
400     OK
400     OK
```

I'm trying to get it to look like, however I would be pivoting about 20 rows (which is why I would like the naming to be dynamic

```
PLACE | OK | NEW | BAD
100     1     1     1
200     0     0     2
300     1     0     0
400     3     0     0
```

From a hodge podge of other questions this is what I've come up with, however, it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct 
                        ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(NAMES)
                 FROM INFO_TABLE with (nolock)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = ' SELECT PLACE ,  ' + @cols + ' 

FROM 
(SELECT 
   CASE 
       WHEN NAME IS NOT NULL
       THEN Count(NAME) 
       ELSE 0 END AS EXPR1, 
       PLACE
       FROM INFO_TABLE with (nolock)) t
PIVOT
( 
AVG(Expr1)
FOR NAME IN (' + @cols + ' )
) 
p ' ;

Execute(@query);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query is close but since you want to `count` the number of `names` you can just use that as the aggregate function, instead of using the `CASE` statement in your subquery and then averaging.

My suggestion would always be to write the query as a static version first before trying to write a dynamic SQL server, mainly to get the syntax correct:

```
select place, Bad, New, OK
from
(
  select place, name
  from info_table
) d
pivot
(
  count(name)
  for name in (Bad, New, OK)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3699/4).  Once you have the logic correct, then you can easily turn this to dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct 
                        ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(NAME)
                 FROM INFO_TABLE with (nolock)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = ' SELECT PLACE ,  ' + @cols + ' 

FROM 
(
   SELECT NAME, PLACE
   FROM INFO_TABLE with (nolock)
) t
PIVOT
( 
  count(name)
  FOR NAME IN (' + @cols + ' )
) 
p ' ;

Execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3699/3)