# Transform existing SQL into a pivot by column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

The following SQL outputs 3 columns:

1. The date (col 1) YYYY-DD
2. MeterReadTypeDescription
3. total

The date repeats because there can be one or more `MeterReadTypeDescription`

What I want, is to be able to pivot, so that the data has dynamic columns headings for each `MeterReadTypeDescription` and below that the totals. This would mean the date in column one would be unique

How do I go about pivoting this SQL based on MeterReadTypeDescription?

```
SELECT 
  convert(char(7), MeterReadDate, 121),
  MeterReadTypes.MeterReadTypeDescription, 
  count(*) as total    
FROM 
  [PremiseMeterReadProviders],
  MeterReadTypes    
WHERE 
  [PremiseMeterReadProviders].MeterReadTypeId = MeterReadTypes.MeterReadTypeId 
  and (MeterReadDate > dateadd(m,-12,getdate()))
GROUP BY
  convert(char(7), MeterReadDate, 121),
  MeterReadTypes.MeterReadTypeDescription
ORDER BY 
  convert(char(7), MeterReadDate, 121)
```

Comment: @paqogomez The second column is `MeterReadTypes.MeterReadTypeDescription`; it's just 1 column

Comment: here is the query:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062032/sql-server-dynamic-pivot?rq=1

Comment: is `MeterReadDate` part of providers or types?

Answer (score 2):

Got it working (thanks igloo for the link)...

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct 
                        ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(MeterReadType)
                 FROM MeterReadView with (nolock)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = ' SELECT MeterReadMonth as Month,  ' + @cols + ' 

FROM 
(
   SELECT MeterReadType, MeterReadMonth,isnull(total,0) as total
   FROM [MeterReadView] with (nolock)
) t
PIVOT
( 
  sum(total)
  FOR MeterReadType IN (' + @cols + ' )
) 
p ' ;

Execute(@query);
```